# Concurrency considerations with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, concurrency

**The setup**

Using Visual Studio, .NET and C#. I am building an Web application which has 2 different purposes:

1. A web application with a quartz job, that connects to an external system to get data and store the data in a SQL Server. This is done every 5 minute. Some data is modified or calculated on before it is saved. I am using the Entity Framework with code-first approach.
2. The other purpose is a REST Web API that gives other systems access to the data that is in the database. Data that is collected by the web application mentioned above.

Both the Web application and the Web API uses the same models as they are both part of the same project. I have a one class that inherits from DbContext, which they both use to get access to the data.

**Now my question.**

I am afraid that I will get concurrency problems. If someone uses the Web API and ask for data while the application itself are busy working on and writing data. Data older than 5 minutes is acceptable, but is it possible for me to run into deadlocks or even wrong data.

What is the best practise here. Maybe 2 different classes that inherits from DbContext? Different connection strings? In other words, how do I make sure that they do not interfere with each other.

**Extra info**

I must say. I have another Web application (with almost the same setup as described above) which has a caching job when it starts. This job runs for 1,5 hours, only reading data, calculating and storing in memory. Now, I also here have a Web API which has serious issues while the job is running in the background. Sometimes half JSON is returned and sometimes timeouts occures. Stopping the caching job fixes everything.

It is because of this, I am asking the question above. Don't want to make the same mistakes again. :)

Comment: Multiple instances of you DbContext should be enough. I don't see a point why you would need multiple DbContext derived class types. Generally: A new DbContext instance on each call is recommended- with concurrency or without, just never store it for a long time.

Comment: This sounds like the way. I think, in the “old” application where I have issues, that I use the same DbContext. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to have all updates from the API done in single transaction. This solution may introduce locking for the readers.
Better option is to load all data from API to staging area and then update primary tables using single transaction. If the amount of data is significant, you may consider renaming tables or 'ALTER TABLE SWITCH' when bringing data to current state.